# Problems related to conceptual understanding of the hypothesis of the mathematical universe

Tags: universe, geometry

The teacher gave a long lecture about Max Tegmark's hypothesis of the mathematical universe, and I realized that apart from Tegmark himself and his followers, few people understand the concept of the hypothesis itself. In short, Tegmark argues that the universe is not simply described by mathematics, but is itself a mathematical structure, just like prime numbers, a sphere, a square, and so on. I don’t understand in any way what this may mean.

One of the consequences of this approach is that each mathematical structure is unique. That is, it is clear that a sphere, as a mathematical object, is unique, because there is no other mathematical object that would be called a sphere. And since the universe is also a mathematical object, it must also be unique in the same sense. But a sphere is just a GEOMETRIC PROPERTY of a physical object. How can a property be a primary entity? And Tegmark says: there are not objects that have properties, but there are properties, like objects.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an opinion, but there seem to be a lot of useless speculative theories in physics at the moment.  The theories should at least make testable predictions for us to take them seriously.

The topic you described may well fit into the 'useless' category and mean nothing.
Others include the multiverse theory, colliding braneworlds etc...

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that Temark is a neo-Pythagorean. It was Pythagoras that first suggested that the nature can be explained with reference to mathematics. This was taken up by Plato who was influenced by Pythagoras in his $Timeaus$ where he used triangles as the basic building blocks of nature. Aristotle also referred to it as:

> The neccessary appears in mathematics and the things which come to be in accordance with nature, in a parallel fashion.

And this explains Wigners remark about 'the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in nature'. It's effective and reasonable because it us the science of the neccesary in nature and in parallel to the neccessary in ideas.

Unfortunately, Tegmark makes no reference to all this prior work in the philosophy of nature and makes a lot of rash, unmotivated claims in his 'philosophy'. In this way, he isn't a Pythagorean at all. Paolo Budinich, a physicist who along with Abdus Salam set up the Trieste Institute of Theoretical Physics called for a healing of the breach between philosophy and physics. A breach, for example, typified by Hawkings disparaging of philosophy. Similar can be said by certain remarks of Feynman. Tegmark's work in this area - in my opinion - goes no way in doing this and brings it into disrepute.